# Regex pattern that matches different arrangements of a string separated by comma

Tags: regex

I want a regex that matches different arrangements of strings separated by `,`

Consider `a,b,c`, I want a pattern that matches all of the following strings:

```
a,b,c
a,c,b
b,a,c
b,c,a
c,a,b
c,b,a
```

The result must have one of the articles (ie:`a` & `b` & `c`), but indifferent to its position in the string.

**Pattern must not match** any strings that hasn't any of the `a` or `b` or `c` characters.

Comment: What should it *not* match? What have you tried? This works for your question as-is but most likely, your question is missing details -  `([abc],?)+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)[abc],[abc],[abc]$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/XbvNrP/1)